Spring Boot Graphql Subscription with graphql-ws protocol
I'm trying to write a graphql client using the spring-boot-starter-graphql library.
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>

I'm trying to connect to a Graphql server using WebSocketGraphQlClient. However, the default websocket protocol used is graphql-transport-ws, so there is a problem with my connection because the server uses the graphql-ws protocol.
WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
WebSocketGraphQlClient graphQlWebSocketClient = WebSocketGraphQlClient
                    .builder("ws://" + this.ip + ":" + this.port + "/subscriptions", webSocketClient)
                    .header("Authorization", "Session " + session.uuid())
                    .build();
String subscription = """
                subscription {
                    userStatusChanged {
                        id
                        createdAt
                        updatedAt
                        username
                        firstName
                        lastName
                        mail
                        role
                    }
                }
                """;
graphQlWebSocketClient.document(subscription)
                .retrieveSubscription("userStatusChanged")
                .toEntity(UserResponse.class)
                .subscribe(userResponse -> log.info(userResponse.toString()),
                        error -> log.info("Error : " + error),
                        () -> log.info("Subscription completed")
                );

The error I get is as follows
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshakeException: Invalid subprotocol. Actual: . Expected one of: graphql-transport-ws
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker.finishHandshake(WebSocketClientHandshaker.java:389) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.WebsocketClientOperations.onInboundNext(WebsocketClientOperations.java:121) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.39.jar:1.0.39]

If I change WebSocketClient to StandardWebSocketClient and add graphql-ws as header, I cannot parse this message because {"type":"ka"} message appears.
WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
WebSocketGraphQlClient graphQlWebSocketClient = WebSocketGraphQlClient
                    .builder("ws://" + this.ip + ":" + this.port + "/subscriptions", webSocketClient)
                    .header("Authorization", "Session " + session.uuid())
                    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "graphql-ws")
                    .build();

The exception is as follows
WebSocketGraphQlTransport   : Closing StandardWebSocketSession[id=0, uri=ws://172.16.60.198:8081/subscriptions]: org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: No matching constant for [ka]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No matching constant for [ka]
 at [Source: (org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBuffer$DefaultDataBufferInputStream); line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: org.springframework.graphql.server.support.GraphQlWebSocketMessage["type"])

If I do not add the Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header, no connection is established.
What should I do for this problem?

Spring for GraphQL does not support this defunct protocol at all. I guess this is using an AWS service?
I would suggest using a different client library unless you can upgrade the protocol to an officially supported one on the server side.
Also see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/965

I solved the problem using Apollo GraphQL Kotlin Client.
